# How to custom mark a newly created Hadoop file?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I want to label the newly created Hadoop backups as unverified. I have come up with three ways:

1. Name change to `file.bak.unverified`
2. Name change to `file.unverified.bak`
3. Create a file called `.unverified` in the directory of `file.bak`.

I think the third way is the most reasonable as it does not change the extension and thus can yield more control if I want to remove this system of putting labels.

However, I am not confident of the best way to implement it. Should I write the backup, commit, and then create a file? This way, it could be the case that post commit, my job fails and there is a backup that does not have .unverified file in it.

Comment: Most hadoop processes write multiple files in directories. Therefore, option 3 makes more sense and will require no rename operations

Answer (score 0):

You may want to think about using an [Access Control LIst](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html#ACLs_.28Access_Control_Lists.29). This just adds permission metadata to the file.  This is likely a good option as there isn't extra small files hanging around to clean up.  This would also make it quick to see what needs verification.